# How to get the last inserted value based ID descending from another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What would be the most convenient way to get the last `Occurance` from 
`@TempTable2` based on `QuoteID DESC` from `@TempTable1`

The expected result should be:

[image]

```
declare @TempTable1 table (QuoteID int, QuoteGUID varchar(50), PolicyNumber varchar(100), Premium money)
insert into @TempTable1 values   (1, 'ABC1','Policy1',100)
                                ,(2, 'ABC2','Policy1',200)
                                ,(3, 'ABC3','Policy1',300)
                                ,(11, 'ABC11','Policy2',150)
                                ,(22, 'ABC22','Policy2',250)
                                ,(33, 'ABC33','Policy2',350)



declare @TempTable2 table (QuoteGUID varchar(50), Occurance money)
insert into @TempTable2 values   ('ABC1',1000)
                                ,('ABC2',2000)
                                ,('ABC3',3000)
                                ,('ABC11',1500)
                                ,('ABC22',2500)
                                ,('ABC33',3500)
--select * from @TempTable2
--select * from @TempTable1
select
     PolicyNumber 
    ,sum(Premium) as Premium
--How can I get the last Occurance from @TempTable2  based on QuoteID DESC from @TempTable1?
    --,t2.Occurance
from @TempTable1 t1
        inner join @TempTable2 t2 ON t1.QuoteGUID = t2.QuoteGUID
group by PolicyNumber
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is using the window function `First_Value()`

**Example**

```
Select PolicyNumber 
      ,Premium = sum(Premium)
      ,Occuance = max(Occuance)
 From (
        select PolicyNumber 
              ,Premium 
              ,Occuance = first_value(Occurance) over (Partition By PolicyNumber Order by QuoteID desc )
        from @TempTable1 t1
                inner join @TempTable2 t2 ON t1.QuoteGUID = t2.QuoteGUID
      ) A
 Group by PolicyNumber
```

**Returns**

```
PolicyNumber    Premium Occuance
Policy1         600.00  3000.00
Policy2         750.00  3500.00
```

Comment: What if the OP use SQL Server 2008 (readers as well)? the `FIRST_VALUE` won't work here cause it's for 2012+. You probably should mention that.

Comment: I'm really not trying to one-up or anything, but I constantly see people using "estimated cost (relative to batch)" as the absolute and only measure of performance. In this case, you need to think about what actually happens in reality, and what happens when there aren't just 6 rows. In particular I focus on reads because, in most cases, we're all memory and I/O-bound, not CPU bound. SQL Server puts too much emphasis on estimated CPU cost as a factor of overall cost, and it's just not valuable anymore. Here the reads stack up like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVPRs.png

Comment: Reads also are not everything, and again I'm not trying to say one query is better than the other. Just trying to dispel the myth that "lowest query cost (relative to the batch)" magically means best performance. Those estimated cost numbers are quite often utter nonsense.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I agree with your comments an insights.  The beauty of SO is that they get options.   A wise man once told me "One test is worth a thousand expert opinions."   I'm sure you'd agree the real benchmark is how it performs in one's actual environment.

Comment: Indeed. I just knee-jerk when someone looks at estimated cost % in a plan and declares performance dominance based on that meaningless number. I try to show where else to look so they can judge for themselves with their system / data, instead of just relying on someone's drive-by comment that one query is superior because of this % stuff.

Answer (score 2):

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT PolicyNumber, 
    Premium = SUM(Premium) OVER (PARTITION BY PolicyNumber), 
    QuoteGUID, 
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PolicyNumber ORDER BY QuoteID DESC)
  FROM @TempTable1 
)
SELECT x.PolicyNumber, x.Premium, y.Occurance
FROM x
INNER JOIN @TempTable2 AS y
ON x.QuoteGUID = y.QuoteGUID
WHERE x.rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, I would use `apply`:

```
select t1.PolicyNumber, t1.Premium, t2.occurance
from @TempTable1 t1 outer apply
     (select top 1 t2.*
      from @TempTable2 t2 
      where t1.QuoteGUID = t2.QuoteGUID
      order by t2.QuoteID desc
     ) t2;
```

Your sample table doesn't have a `QuoteId`.  And I don't see any need for aggregation.

Comment: Yes. Only `@TempTable1`  has a QuoteID. Thats the problem.

Comment: You need aggregation to sum t1.premium.